# Counting running total on time series where condition is X

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL table of date entries with three columns: date, item, and status. The table appears like this:

| date | item | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | A | on |
| 2023-01-01 | B | on |
| 2023-01-01 | C | off |
| 2023-01-02 | A | on |
| 2023-01-02 | B | off |
| 2023-01-02 | C | off |
| 2023-01-02 | D | on |
| 2023-01-03 | A | on |
| 2023-01-03 | B | off |
| 2023-01-03 | C | off |
| 2023-01-03 | D | off |

Looking at the most recent entries, I need grouped by item, the latest date and status, and a count on the running total of entries where status has not changed. For example, the output I am looking for would be:

| latest_date | item | current_status | number_of_days_on_current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-03 | A | on | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | B | off | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | C | off | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | D | off | 1 |

How would I get the output I want in PostgreSQL 13.7?

This returns the latest date, item, and current status, but does not correctly count the number of days the item has been on the current status:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    item, 
    date, 
    status, 
    LAG(status) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS prev_status, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM 
    schema.table
)
SELECT 
  MAX(date) AS latest_date, 
  item, 
  status AS current_status, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN prev_status = status THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS number_of_days
FROM 
  CTE 
WHERE 
  rn = 1 
GROUP BY
item, status, prev_status, date
ORDER BY 
  item
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `cte` to build the runs of consecutive statuses:

```
with recursive cte(s_date, date, item, status, s_count, result) as (
    select e.date, e.date, e.item, e.status, 1, '[]'::jsonb from entries e 
    left join entries e1 on e1.item = e.item and e.date - interval '1 day' = e1.date where e1.date is null
    union all
    select c.s_date, e.date, c.item, e.status, 
      case when e.status = c.status then c.s_count + 1 else 1 end, 
      case when e.status = c.status then c.result else c.result || jsonb_build_object('s', c.status, 'c', c.s_count) end 
    from cte c join entries e on e.item = c.item and c.date + interval '1 day' = e.date
)
select date(t1.md), t1.item, e.status, (select max(((v -> 'c')#>>'{}')::int) 
      from jsonb_array_elements(r::jsonb) v where (v -> 's')#>>'{}' = e.status) 
    from (select t.s_date, t.item, max(t.date) md, max(t.result::text) r 
 from (select c.s_date, c.date, c.item, c.result || jsonb_build_object('s', c.status, 'c', c.s_count) result from cte c) t
group by t.s_date, t.item) t1
join entries e on e.item = t1.item and date(e.date) = date(t1.md)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0_JS3AzW).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe I can clarify though, I am looking for the consecutive days that status has not changed from the current status. If you add an entry ('2023-01-01','D','off') so that item D goes 'off' -> 'on' -> 'off', I need the output result to still show 1 (day), and this gives '2'

Comment: @rs Please see my recent edit (updated fiddle includes the addition of `('2023-01-01','D','off')`)

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, you want to find the max count of consecutive statuses `where status = last status value`, this became a gaps and islands problem. This can be solved using a difference between two row_numbers and the `last_value` function as the following:

```
with last_status as
(
  select *, 
      last_value(status) over (partition by item order by date_ 
        range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) current_status,
      max(date_) over (partition by item) latest_date,
      row_number() over (partition by item order by date_) -
      row_number() over (partition by item, status order by date_) grp
  from table_name
),
consecutive_status_counts as
(
  select latest_date, item, current_status, status, count(*) cnt
  from last_status 
  where current_status = status
  group by latest_date, item, current_status, status, grp 
)
select latest_date, 
       item,
       current_status, 
       max(cnt) number_of_days_on_current
from consecutive_status_counts
group by latest_date, item, current_status
order by item
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SnaTvXLs)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe I can clarify though, I am looking for the consecutive days that status has not changed from the current status. If you add an entry  ('2023-01-01','D','off') so that item D goes 'off' -> 'on' -> 'off', I need the output result to still show 1 (day), and this gives '2'

Comment: You are welcome, I had doubted that you want this from the beginning, but it wasn't clear enough (you didn't say *consecutive* in your post). Anyway, I updated the answer according to this.